# How do I extend SymPy pretty printing for new structures in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: symbolic-computation

**Note 1:** I am asking this on Math Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow, where most SymPy questions are, because [StackOverflow doesn't have MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106281/mathjax-should-also-work-in-stackoverflow), making it very difficult to pose the question.

**Note 2:** There is no `sympy` tag on Math Stack Exchange, making it also difficult to get the right audience for the question, so [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22).

In Jupyter notebook if we execute this code:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
x,y=sp.symbols('x,y')
x**2+sp.sin(y)
```

We will get a nice output, with no further coding, due to [SymPy's pretty printing process](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html), that looks like

$x^2 + \sin{y}$

Now suppose we do:

```
class MetricSpace:
    def __init__(self, M, d):
        self.M = M
        self.d = d
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"$({self.M}, {self.d})$ {self.__class__.__name__}"

Re,d=sp.symbols(r'\Re,d')

MetricSpace(Re,d)
```

Then the output we get is

```
$(\Re, d)$ MetricSpace
```

If we do instead

```
from IPython.core.display import Markdown
Markdown(repr(MetricSpace(Re,d)))
```

then I get the desired output, which looks like

- $(\Re, d)$ MetricSpace

**Question:** How do we code the above so that SymPy's pretty printer provides the desired output in Jupyter notebok without having to wrap it in `Markdown(repr(...))`?

Comment: Hi! Good question, although it would fit much better on SO, I think. If I were you I would ask it there, attaching screenshots of your desired typesetting.

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342423/how-do-i-extend-sympy-pretty-printing-for-new-structures-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: This is solved in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342423/how-do-i-extend-sympy-pretty-printing-for-new-structures-in-jupyter-notebook).